# Regex — Character occuring more than x number of times in a string (in different positions)

Tags: regex, perl, character

I need regex to find when "@" has more than 10 occurrences. The string will contain email addresses, comma separated, so @s will never be next to each other.

What I have is @{10,} only works if there are 10 @s in a row.  I need for it to work when there is 10+ @s in the string.  TIA!

Comment: Technically, [`@` is allowed in the local part of an email address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax), so just counting the number of `@`s could give you an incorrect result. I think the more "correct" approach would be to parse your list with a CSV parser, but of course that will only work if you have a properly quoted and escaped CSV, since commas are also allowed in emails.

Comment: I don't agree that a regex is the best way to handle this, but if you insist upon it, you could simply do `/(\@.+){10,}/`, which would allow for 1 or more characters to separate all 10 (or more) instances of `@`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following pattern matches strings with more than 10 `@`:

```
@.*@.*@.*@.*@.*@.*@.*@.*@.*@.*@
```

After being optimized (`.` ⇒ `[^@]`), having redundancies removed, and being embedded into a match operator, it becomes the following:

```
/\@(?:[^\@]*\@){10}/
```

At one point, you said you wanted to find "10+" instead of "more than 10". For that, you'd use.

```
/\@(?:[^\@]*\@){9}/
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, you can count the number of matches in a regex using the "saturn" operator.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = 'a@b.com, m@b.ca, x@c@@@d@xxxxx@@@, @';

my $count =()= $str =~ /@/g;

if ($count > 10){
    ...
}
```

Here's an example without the intermediary `$count` variable:

```
if ((() = $str =~ /@/g) > 10){
```

That said, I'm with the others who commented in that regex may not be the best approach here.

Comment: Ugh, why is it called a goatse operator? You're bringing back terrible memories.

Comment: I read your answer, wondered what a _saturn_ operator is and was kind of relieved to find the other name down here.